# which document reindex when nested documents add or update

Tags: elasticsearch

refer
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

> To update, add, or remove a nested object, we have to reindex the
>   whole document.

In this content, 'whole' mean

1. all document in single type that has the document
2. single document that updated, added, or removed

Answer (score 0):

A nested object is just a component of a single document.

```
{
  "users" : [
    { "username" : "pickypg", "country" : "US" }
  ]
}
```

If `users` is the nested array, then each object in it is a nested document. Every change to that array (add, update, or delete) causes all nested documents in the array to be rewritten with it.

On a related note: you never need to use nested type unless it's going to be an array in general (not all documents must make use of it, but at least some of them should or it's a big waste).

Not coincidentally, the entire document is also rewritten. The real burden is that each nested document, unlike the normal, whole documents, adds *extra* work when the segments get written.

Comment: I need nested document whose array will be searched. If I have 2 users and one of them's nested document has been changed, just the user document will be re-indexed. Am I right?